# object FlinkKafkaConsumer010 is not a member of package org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, sbt, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to assembly a little program to connect to kafka topic using apache flink. I need to use FlinkKafkaConsumer010.

```
package uimp
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.TimeCharacteristic
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.SimpleStringSchema
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.{FlinkKafkaConsumer010}
import java.util.Properties

object Silocompro {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
 // set up the execution environment
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.ProcessingTime)

    val propertiesTopicDemographic = new Properties()
    propertiesTopicDemographic.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "bigdata.dataspartan.com:19093")
    propertiesTopicDemographic.setProperty("group.id", "demographic")

    val myConsumerDemographic = new FlinkKafkaConsumer010[String]("topic_demographic", new 
    SimpleStringSchema(), propertiesTopicDemographic)

    val messageStreamDemographic = env
      .addSource(myConsumerDemographic)
      .print()


    env.execute("Flink Scala API Skeleton")

   }
 }
```

My problem is when a try to assembly my program with this build.sbt, the compiler returns an error "object FlinkKafkaConsumer010 is not a member of package org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka":

```
      ThisBuild / resolvers ++= Seq("Apache Development Snapshot Repository" at 
      "https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/",Resolver.mavenLocal)

      name := "silocompro"

      version := "1.0"

      organization := "uimp"

      ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.12.11"

      val flinkVersion = "1.9.0"

      val flinkDependencies = Seq(
         "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-scala" % flinkVersion % "provided",
         "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-streaming-scala" % flinkVersion % "provided",
         "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-core"% flinkVersion % "provided",
         "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-connector-kafka-base" % flinkVersion % "provided",
         "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-clients" % flinkVersion % "provided",
         "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-connector-kafka" % flinkVersion % "provided")

      lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
      settings( libraryDependencies ++= flinkDependencies)


      assembly / mainClass := Some("uimp.Silocompro")

      Compile / run  := Defaults.runTask(Compile / fullClasspath,
                               Compile / run / mainClass,
                               Compile / run / runner
                              ).evaluated

 
      Compile / run / fork := true
      Global / cancelable := true

      assembly / assemblyOption  := (assembly / assemblyOption).value.copy(includeScala = false)
```

What is the reason of this dependency error?

Answer (score 0):

The connectors are not part of the flink-binary, this means that you need to have connectors in `compile` scope, so this basically means that you need to remove the `provided` from those dependencies. In this setting the app will work on cluster.

BUT, if You want to run it locally without starting the cluster then You should have all the flink dependencies in `compile` scope i.e. remove all `provided` scope declarations.

Comment: I have removed all provided scope declarations, but I have still errors when I assembly my program, "object connectors is not a a member of package org.apache.flink.streaming"

Answer (score 0):

In the end I had a problem of dependencies. I have done some actions:

1. I have added a new resolver
   https:/oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories
2. I have uninstalled
   plugin metals(scala) from VS Code
3. I have added"org.apache.flink"%% "flink-connector-kafka-0.10"%flinkVersion - tomy flinkDependencies

And after this actions I solved my library dependencies problem. Thanks